# subgroup of permulation using cyclic notation and cosets of $S_4$ and $A_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K=\{ (1),(12)(34), (13)(24),(14)(23)\}$

(a)show that it is a subgroup of $A_4$
and hence of $S_4$

(b) state number of cosets in K $in $ $A_4$

c) state  number of cosets of $K$ in $S_4$ 
*dont list them*

---

comfortable with permutation matrix. Not sure what $A_4$ means but the permutation the elements. feel that can show it is a subgroup by having to do a 4 by 4 table.

---

**Attempt 1**

still multiplying out but its a bad  Idea
$$\begin{aligned}
\\(1)*(1)&=(1)
\\(1) * (12)(34)&=(12)(34)
\\(1)* (23)(24)&=(13)(24)
\\(1)* (4)(23)&=(14)(23)
\end{aligned} $$

$$\begin{aligned}
\\(12)(34) * (12)(34)&=
\\(12)(34)* (23)(24)&=
\\(12)(34)* (4)(23)&=
\end{aligned} $$

Answer (score 0):

a) You're correct in trying to multiply everything out, though there might just be a shorter way of doing it.  To show it's a subgroup of $A_4$ you also need to say why each element is in $A_4$ though.

b) Lagrange's theorem is the way to go here.

c) Again, Lagrange's theorem will help you out.

Comment: I know that $|S_4|=!4=4*3*2*1=24$ so for eeach coset it depends of each element in the group how many itself geenrates and dived it by 24 to find the lements of each coset . Not sure what will be the case of $A_4$

Comment: Careful with the notation, while you're correct that $|S_4| = 24$, the notation $!4$ refers to something different than $4 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1$, the correct notation is $4!$.